# Changing hover color using tailwind

Tags: css, angular, tailwind-css, stenciljs

I want to change the color of the icon with mouse over using tailwind
from this [image]

to this [image]

this what i have done but it is not working

```
.btn {
@apply  agt-h-10 agt-w-10 agt-bg-zinc-100 agt-rounded-full agt-flex agt-justify-center
}

.img{
   @apply agt-w-full  hover:agt-fill-black
}
```

PS : I am using tailwindcss and agt it is just n internal library

Comment: are you using icon or svg?

Comment: i am using svg ,i want to change the fill color

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide `class` to your parent `div` of `icon` and in `css` file you need to change color of `svg` on `hover`. Like this,

```
.changeColor:hover svg>path {
    stroke: "#f00"
}
```

Comment: seems not working ,yes i provided a class to my icon : this what i have done but also not working  ``` .img{
 @apply  hover:agt-fill-white 
}
.img:hover{
    fill: white !important;
} ```

Comment: provide code in code sandbox do I can try on it.